# pass multiple id's from checkboxes to my controller with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, controller, parameter-passing

I have a products table in my database. I'm getting the name of the products from my DB and print theire names in a bootstrap table on my blade. Currently there is a edit button on every row line. If I'm pressing the button I'm passing the ID of this product to my controller edit function. Now I want to add checkboxes for every product in this table and if I set for example two ticks ( so two different products ) I want to pass both ID's at the same time to my controller.

Looks like this:

```
            {!! Form::open(['action' => 'ProductController@tags']) !!}
            @foreach($products as $product)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {!! Form::checkbox('check', $product->id) !!}
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        {{ $product->name  }}
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    @foreach($product->tags as $tag)
                        {{$tag->name}},
                    @endforeach
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        {{ $product->created_at->format('d.m.y')  }}
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <a href="{{ action('ProductController@edit', ['id' => $product->id]) }}">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" style="float: right;">Edit</button>
                    </a>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

As you see, I've set the product id as a seccond parameter for every checkbox, but this haven't worked well of course. Can someone tell me a way how I can give every checkbox the ID of the product and pass their ID's to my controller at the same time, if they are marked with a tick ?

Thanks for taking the time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried accepting multiple checkbox values as array by adding '[]' to the checkbox name?

```
{!! Form::checkbox('check[]', $product->id) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this Form facade was from Laravel 4, i never used it, but i think that this will generate an input, with checkbox type, a name of 'check' and the id as the value, right?

Did you tried to set the name to 'check[]'? This way all checked ids will be in one array 'check' in your request. In Laravel 5 at least, you can try to dump the request['check'] and this should return an array os checked ids